# Microsoft teams deep link how to pass query parameters

Tags: microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I have created a custom bot, with yo teams generator, which is also registered in azure. In addition, I have a deeplink to this bot in order to display a task module, when clicked from teams, with html/javascript content. But I want this content to be dynamic and incject some values from my database into this content and to achieve this I must have the names of my database and my collection. Is it possible to add some query parameters into deeplink like we do in ordinary url links (e.g ?key=value), so I can query my database from the custom app?

Comment: @christos.goulas- Could you please share the deep link URL or document which you are following , so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I manage to figure it out. My deep link is something like this: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/{APP_ID}?url=https://{DOMAIN}/story?name%3dhello%26last%3dworld. So in order to be able to pass query parameters I have to encode some symbols like = and & as above. Now I can grap for example the name and last variables from the above url

Answer (score 1):

deep link: teams.microsoft.com/l/task{APP_ID}?url=https://{DOMAIN}/story?name%3dhello%26last%3dworld.
So in order to be able to pass query parameters. Encode some symbols like = and & as above.Now you can grap for example the name and last variables from the above url.